# CAAnimationDelegate delegates are never called

Tags: ios, swift, cabasicanimation

I made a simple progress line using two `CAShapeLayer's`. Animation works correctly but the `CAAnimationDelegate` `animationDidStart` and `animationDidStop` are never called.

Here is my code:

```
class ProgressBar: UIView, CAAnimationDelegate {

    var bottomProgressBar = CAShapeLayer()
    var topProgressBar = CAShapeLayer()
    let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "strokeEnd")

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        configure()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        configure()
    }

    func configure() {
        animation.delegate = self

        // setup the two layers
    }

    func animate(toValue: Double) {

        animation.duration = 1.0
        animation.fromValue = 0
        animation.toValue = toValue

        topProgressBar.strokeEnd = CGFloat(toValue)
        topProgressBar.animation(forKey: "animate")
    }

    func animationDidStart(_ anim: CAAnimation) {
        print("start")
    }

    func animationDidStop(_ anim: CAAnimation, finished flag: Bool) {
        print("stop")
    }
}
```

`animate` method is called multiple times with values ranging from 0 to 1.

Does anyone know why these delegates are never called ?

Comment: Are you ever adding the animation to a `CALayer`?

Comment: Is `topProgressBar.animation(forKey: "animate")` supposed to be `topProgressBar.add(animation, forKey: "animate")`?

Comment: I/m never adding it. Should I ? Because for me this code works. But now I want see when the animation starts and finishes and this part doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: add correct solution with links per comment below

You are calling topProgressBar.[animation(forKey: "animate")](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/calayer/1410808-animation) which actually returns the animation; it doesn't start it.  You should call [layer.add(animation, forKey:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/calayer/1410848-add) instead

Comment: Apparently I have to add the animation to the CAShapeLayer, then it's called

Comment: Yes I am looking at my code and you have to call layer.add(animation, forKey:)  instead you are calling topProgressBar.animation(forKey: "animate") which actually returns the animation; it doesn't start it

Comment: Can u update the answer with this ? And I will accept it. Thanks.